# En .NET, ¿existe alguna forma de transformar un archivo SVG en un gráfico PNG?

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net

Los navegadores nos muestran archivos SVG transformándolos en gráficos. La cuestión es dado un archivo SVG -que en realidad es un documento XML-, ¿existe alguna forma de convertirle en un archivo gráfico como PNG, GIF o JPG?

Answer (score 2):

Buenas Rafael,

Existe una herramienta de código abierto que hace esta función llamada `InkScape` la cual tiene una interfaz de línea de comandos.

Puedes hacer un código para recibir el archivo `SVG` y ejecutar la aplicación pasandole unos argumentos específicos para que te convierta la imagen en `PNG`.

[Link del ejemplo donde explica el proceso.](http://harriyott.com/2008/05/converting-svg-images-to-png-in-c)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! ¡Voy a probar si funciona!

Answer (score 1):

Para hacerlo desde C#, puedes usar Magick.NET, que es un wrapper para ImageMagick:

https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

Comment: ¡Probaré la solución! ¡Muchas gracias!